# Не могу установить Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь установить Laravel, ставлю:

```
# composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist .
```

Получаю такой процесс установки:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.31)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.31)
    Loading from cache

Created project in .
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.8 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.7 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.6 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.5 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.4 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.39 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.38 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.37 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.36 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.35 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.34 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.33 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.32 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.31 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.30 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.3 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.29 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.28 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.27 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.26 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.25 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.24 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.23 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.22 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.21 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.20 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.2 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.19 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.18 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.17 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.16 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.15 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.14 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.13 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.12 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.11 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.10 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.1 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires symfony/http-foundation 2.8.*|3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/http-foundation[2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
```

Версия PHP:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.0.8 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2016 16:24:08) ( NTS )
```

Расширения PHP:

```
# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
interbase
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_dblib
PDO_Firebird
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
pspell
readline
recode
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в отсутствующих тегах на [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-foundation).
Вот соответствующий Issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19376
И связанный с ним: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19375

Процитирую [Tobion](https://github.com/Tobion):

> Seems like all tags are missing on packagist:
>   https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-foundation but they exist
>   in git https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/tags
>
> Other components have the tags on packagist e.g.
>   https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/yaml

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, ребята из Gitter-а по Laravel помогли разобраться, правда не понятно что было, но все поставилось в итоге.

Comment: Так что конкретно вы сделали?

Comment: Возможно проблема была и в том, что вы описали выше, но мне показалось что у меня проблема была из-за включенного на сервере Selinux, отключил его и стало все нормально устанавливаться.